# htaccess/htpasswd internal error

Tags: .htaccess

I wanted to make a simple http authentification,but it throws internal server error. I've already tried all alternatives of path, but it still cannot open password file. Htpasswd has correct rights and it's readable.

Htaccess:

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /www/m/s/u10395/public_html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Here's the output of error_log:

[authn_file:error] [pid 44106:tid 34464533504] (2)No such file or directory: [client 85.237.234.17:18822] AH01620: Could not open password file: /www/m/s/u10395/public_html/.htpasswd

Isn't there anything what could cause this problem? Thanks.